# How to return function in Google Sheet through AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I want to print the List of GA accounts through custom Menu in Google Sheet Interface. I gathered this code in my App Script. When I run, the list account function, it works perfectly fine - https://prnt.sc/uvfag3

I want to print this in Google Sheet Interface. Below is my code

```
 function listAccounts() { 
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = sheet.getActiveSheet(); 
  var data = ss.getDataRange();
 

  var accounts = Analytics.Management.Accounts.list();
  if (accounts.items && accounts.items.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < accounts.items.length; i++) {
      var account = accounts.items[i];
      Logger.log(account.name, account.id);

     
    }
  } 
}

function onOpen () {

var ui= SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu("Client Accounts")
      .addItem('List GA Accounts', 'listAccounts')
      .addToUi();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by `Google Sheet Interface` you mean writing the data to your spreadsheet, you could use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to format your data as a 2D array, and [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) to write that data into your sheet:

```
function listAccounts() { 
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = sheet.getActiveSheet(); 
  var accounts = Analytics.Management.Accounts.list();
  if (accounts.items && accounts.items.length) {
    var values = accounts.items.map(item => [item.name, item.id]);
    ss.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  } 
}
```

#### Note:

I'm not sure where in your sheet you want to write the data to, so in the sample below, it's starting from the first row and column (`A1`). If that's not the case, please modify the first two parameters of:

```
ss.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
```

#### Reference:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: Yes work perfectly. Thanks for the answer. Quick Question - What does values[0] means? Is this array index.

Comment: @ArifAhmed Yes, `values[0]` refers to the first element of the `values` array. It is used because the range you're writing your values to needs to have the same dimensions as the `values` themselves.